# Running a job right now using whenever?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

Currently, I am using the whenever gem to schedule a task as such:

```
every :reboot do
    script_runner "lib/initialize.rb"
end
```

However, I only want to run this task once (ideally when the person types whenever -i) instead of running it on every reboot. Is there any way to achieve this? I have checked the documentation on https://github.com/javan/whenever but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: define a custom method, why need of `whenever` for it.

Comment: Thanks, will do, don't know what I was thinking.